# Limit the number of rows of a column a user has based on parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a call-tracking application as a way to learn rails and twilio.

Right now, I have the model scheme plans has_many users has_many phones.

In the plans model, I have a parameter called max_phone_numbers.

What I'd like to do is to limit the number of phones a user has based on the max_phone_numbers the plan gives.

The flow looks something like this :

1) User buys a bunch of phone numbers
2)When User.phones.count = max_phone numbers, then ability to buy more phone numbers is disabled, and a link pops up to the upgrade_path

I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing this though. What are the combinations of things I would need to do in my model, and in my controller?

***What would I define in my controller, in such a way that in the view I can warp if/then statements around the buttons?***

i.e if limit is reached, than show this, else show button

***What would I put in my models to prevent someone from just visiting the link instead?***

Any guidance, or resources on doing something like this would be greatly appreciated

Here's my current user model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                  :string(255)
#  email                 :string(255)
#  created_at            :datetime         not null
#  updated_at            :datetime         not null
#  password_digest       :string(255)
#  remember_token        :string(255)
#  twilio_account_sid    :string(255)
#  twilio_auth_token     :string(255)
#  plan_id               :integer
#  stripe_customer_token :string(255)
#

# Twilio authentication credentials

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :plan_id, :stripe_card_token
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
  validates_presence_of :plan_id

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end

    def create_twilio_subaccount     
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_PARENT_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_PARENT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
      @subaccount = @client.accounts.create({:FriendlyName => self[:email]})
      self.twilio_account_sid = @subaccount.sid
      self.twilio_auth_token  = @subaccount.auth_token
      save!
    end

  private

      def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end


end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a custom validation to your Phone model to check if a user has reached their limit. That would prevent any new Phone's from being created if the user has reached their limit.

In your User class

```
def at_max_phone_limit?
  self.phones.count >= self.plan.max_phone_numbers
end
```

In your Phone class

```
validate :check_phone_limit, :on => :create

def check_phone_limit
  if User.find(self.user_id).at_max_phone_limit?
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot add any more phones"
  end
end
```

In your view/form, you would do something like this

```
<% if @user.at_max_phone_limit? %>
  <%= link_to "Upgrade your Plan", upgrade_plan_path %>
<% else %>
  # Render form/widget/control for adding a phone number
<% end %>
```

Comment: Zeikt, this is genius. Thanks so much for helping deconstruct this. I'll implement it today or tomorrow and let you know how it goes.